# Bake Tables with Uppercase

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I am installing the cake 3.0 in a database outside the convention, all the tables are with capital letter making the bake return this error:

Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.c_a_d_b_e_m' doesn't exist in [/var/www/project/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php, line 130]

Do you have any way to set up Inflector to identify the bake tables with capital letter ?

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to be helpful when using non-standard table names:

```
$> php bin/cake.php bake model PLURAL_MODEL_NAME_HERE --table NON_STANDARD_TABLE_NAME_HERE
```

Then, you can run the template / controllers

```
$> php bin/cake.php bake controller PLURAL_MODEL_NAME_HERE
$> php bin/cake.php bake template PLURAL_MODEL_NAME_HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the bake utility can't bake everything for you if the existing datasource is not following convention. You will need to create the [Table Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html) yourself and set the custom table names in there. So for the example you've shown, create a `src/Model/Table/Cadbem.php` file and set the custom table name it it's `initialize` method:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class CadbemTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('CADBEM');
    }

}
```

Once you have that, you can create the Controllers/Views with the bake utility based on this table object.

Comment: Thanks for help, 
I created the Table Object as you told and still giving the error.

Comment: Inside bin folder of cake3 on linux runned ./cake bake model CADBEM